# Creating JSON from Database Table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am saving some settings in a table because it changes frequently and is different for each user. Following is my table structure.

```
DECLARE @tem AS TABLE
(
    id INT,
    Person VARCHAR(100),
    JLabel NVARCHAR(100),
    JValue NVARCHAR(200),
    Parent INT
);

INSERT @tem
(
    id,
    Person,
    JLabel,
    JValue,
    Parent
)
VALUES
(1,'arun', 'Area', '250', NULL),
(2,'arun', 'brder', NULL, NULL),
(3,'arun', 'width', '5', 2)
(4,'arun', 'marker', NULL, NULL),
(5,'arun', 'dataLabel', NULL, 4),
(6,'arun', 'visible', '1', 5),
(7,'arun', 'position', 'Top', 5),
(8,'arun', 'font', NULL, 5),
(9,'arun', 'fontWeight', '600', 8),
(10,'arun', 'color', '#ffffff', 8);


--EXPECTED OUTPUT
{"Area":"250","brder":{"width":"5"},"marker": { "dataLabel": { "visible": "1", "position": "Top", "font": { "fontWeight": "600", "color": "#ffffff" } } }}
```

Here width is the child element of border because it's Parent is 2 (id of border).
How do I get this output?

Comment: Have you had a look at `FOR JSON`?

Comment: Though, I must admit, I don't see how `width` is a "child" of `brder`; can you elaborate where that relationship comes from?

Comment: @Larnu it's Parent is 2 (id of border).

Comment: @Larnu yes I tried FOR JSON but its output is different from my requirements

Comment: Can you have other rows that are related to others? For example a row `height` that is related to the `Area`?  What would the JSON look like is `brder` also had a value for `JValue`? Are you only limited to these values for `JLabel`?

Comment: @Larnu I added some more rows

Comment: Honestly, I think you might be better off doing this in the application layer, due to the EAV design of your data.

Comment: @Larnu JValue for brder is another JSON string that's why it's JValue is NULL.  If JLabel is parent then it's JValue is NULL